# Python list of coordinates

Tags: python

I've got a list of sequences of points(coordinates) in python. I need a list with just all the points, without the dividing of sequences.  Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your list look like? Show us at least a part of it if you want someone to be able to help you.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Edit your question to add some sample data, and what the processed result should be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flattening a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

If your list of sequences is represented like the following:

```
 point_sequences_lst = [[a,b,c,], [d,e,f,g,o], [a,f,e,a,c,e,f,g,e,f]] # a list of 3 sequences of points
```

Then you can make one list using  list comprehensions

```
 point_lst = [point for sequence in point_sequences_lst for point in sequence]
```